# Extract values from CSV-like string including empty fields with PCRE regex

Tags: regex, string, csv, split, pcre

I try to capture values of columns including(!) empty columns from multiple csv-like simple data column strings, seperated by a semicolon. And even if I know that regex isn't the best approach for that and explicit csv parsers would do a quite better job, in this case I have no other choice than to use PRCE regex to build html table `<td>` groups from this data.

The worsed example which should (still) work, looks like this:

```
;testvalue;"testvalue";"test "val"ue";test value;
```

... which should be literally interpreted like this:

```
empty | testvalue | testvalue | test "val"ue | test value | empty
```

... which gets finally rendered into this (not part of the question):

```
<td>empty</td>
<td>testvalue</td>
<td>testvalue</td>
<td>test"val"ue</td>
<td>test value</td>
<td>empty</td>
```

(UPDATE like asked of @anubhava)

Sadly there is another *downer* coming with it: The system where it will be implemented has a fixed way to handle the strings. It will ONLY recognize and ONLY alter captured groups of the string. Any other unregistered part of the string gets directly printed out with the rest *as-is*. That means: we need to **register** the semicolons in the regex, even if we don't want them to be printed out, but to remove them by ignoring their matching group.

Usually, it would be enough to only print out the captured group, but this doesn't work here. To ONLY capture the values would cause this output:

```
;;;;;
<td>empty</td>
<td>testvalue</td>
<td>testvalue</td>
<td>test"val"ue</td>
<td>test value</td>
<td>empty</td>
```

*Maybe we need to capture the whole string first in another group or we need to capture the semicolons in another group to throw them away later in the print out?* ...

Comment: ok, I'll update my question to take the problem described by @Stavr00 with multiple inline quotes into account.

Comment: Sry I had to remove the favoured answer flag from Saleems answer again, since it seems still not the best solution. Thanks for all effort til here but there are signs for that the shorter approach below uses less resources since it needs less steps even if quite not perfect yet. And to create a replacement pattern we need to get rid off the semicolons, So, we need 2 ((capture) groups), one for the extracted value $1 and the other 2nd (;) $2 for the trash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this much simpler regex with a lookbehind with included semicolons in a 3rd capture group:

```
$str = ';testvalue;"testvalue";"test "val"ue";test value;';
preg_match_all('/(?<=;|^)("?)([^;]*)\1(;|$)/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[2]);
```

`(?<=;|^)` is a positive lookbehind to make sure we're matching `[^;]*` only after line start or a `;`.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] => testvalue
    [2] => testvalue
    [3] => test "val"ue
    [4] => test value
    [5] =>
)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wY5zJ9/7)

And to get the required HTML:

```
echo "<td>" . implode("</td>\n<td>", $matches[2]) . "</td>\n";

<td></td>
<td>testvalue</td>
<td>testvalue</td>
<td>test "val"ue</td>
<td>test value</td>
<td></td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and effort! This is an awesome and short approach, with less process steps required. I have updated your regex101 to build capture groups for the extracted column values with () here https://regex101.com/r/wY5zJ9/2 - Would you mind to add the feature of "inline "q"uotes" like updated in the OP question? Then I would like to rather favour your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Wow, you are awesome. thanks for your fast reply. Almost there :-) *hides* sry, look at the 4th version here: https://regex101.com/r/wY5zJ9/4 -> It shows the problem with multiple inline quotes still there. We also still need to capture (;) in a 2nd match group to throw them away in the replacement building otherwise they are not removed. Look at the updated question. Thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108557/discussion-between-anubhava-and-nilsun).

Comment: This is the best answer with the smartest solution and best for performance (less steps). Thanks a million for all the time and effort. Awesome answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try following PCRE regex:

```
\"(?:.*?)\"(?=;|$)|(?<=(?:;))(?:.*?)(?=;|$)|^(?:[^;]*?)(?=;)
```

From sample string `;testvalue;"testvalue";"test value";test value;` regex will capture:

```
Match 1:             
Match 2:    testvalue
Match 3:    "testvalue"
Match 4:    "test value"
Match 5:    test value
Match 6:
```

See demo at https://regex101.com/r/sU2jK5/2

Comment: awesome! thank you. Is it ok that I put it all in () to create the respective capture groups ;-) ? Than it would be perfect! Thank you a million for your fast reply.

Comment: Inline quotes will not work properly: `test ""A"" value` should be parsed as `test "A" value`

Comment: This appears to be so complicated and inefficient as well.

Comment: @Stavr00 hm, good point. need to test further ... maybe we can update this answer then with Saleem.

Comment: CSV parsing is very complicated. My solution is more sort of hint and is not perfect but can be improved.

Comment: @Saleem its a very good hint, thank you! Would you mind to except my edit for the capture group () ? It should by in your in box or notice area (peer review)

Comment: @nilsun I don't see any problem with regex. see https://regex101.com/r/sU2jK5/2. and yes, I'll be glad to review.

Comment: @Saleem you can decline my edit when you put the regex from https://regex101.com/r/sU2jK5/2 exactly as is from your comment in your answer, because it works out of the box including inline quotes. Thank you.